# Make responsive image fit parent container

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out if there is a pure CSS solution to ensure the image within my banner doesn't go below the height of the parent but keep ratio of the image.

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LkxYU/1/

html:

```
<div class="banner_holder">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/800/600"/>    
</div>
```

css:

```
.banner_holder{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    outline:1px dotted red;
}

.banner_holder img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

My aim is to have the image always 100%, but never below 300px in height. This would mean image cutoff, but thats fine, i just want to know if there is a pure CSS solution, or if i need to use jQuery

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of using an < img > tag, I made that image the background-image for a div and gave it the following styles:

```
.banner_holderImage{
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    background:   url("http://placekitten.com/g/800/600")no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

here's the fiddle I was using: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/LkxYU/4/

Here's the complete HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="banner_holder">
    <div class="banner_holderImage"></div>  
</div>
```

--

```
.banner_holder{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    outline:1px dotted red;
}

.banner_holderImage{
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    background:   url("http://placekitten.com/g/800/600")no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why i didnt think of background image! Thank you for the great answer

Comment: Background image doesn't work with Google Robots and Spiders so the image will not available for search. Should not be used in case of products or items to be displayed and searchable

Comment: @Raffaeu you can add background images to your sitemap using image tag definitions. See more here - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636

While it's a slight work around, it is a false assumption to say that google can't crawl background images.

Comment: Good to know I wasn't aware of this

Answer (score 1):

Your image will inevitably be out of ratio depending on the screen size, why not try a background image:

```
.banner_holder{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  outline:1px dotted red;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/800/600') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

or you could just add a max height to your image tag:

```
.banner_holder img{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.banner_holder img{
height: 100%;
/* OR */
height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use max-height and max-width to be sure that image will always fit the parent div:

```
.banner_holder{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    outline:1px dotted red;
}

.banner_holder img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I miss the part where you wrote about 300px cut-off stuff :) MathiasaurusRex's answer is correct.