# Empty Space when image has max-width:100% - responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive layout and I want my images to fill their containers. When I use `max-width` and no `height` there is some empty space near the bottom of the images.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8SvpQ/

Is what I am doing not possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use `width:100%;` with `height:auto;` and `display:block;`

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
/* ADD THIS */
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

`display:block;` will remove some unwanted `box-model` spacing under the image

Comment: Thanks Jason. Before you posted this I added `vertical-align: top` and it solved the problem as well. I will go with your suggestion but is either of the two 'better practice?' Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "best practice" is, and I wouldn't know why `display:block;` wouldn't be. Technically you are changing the image from `display:inline;` to `block`.

Answer (score 1):

just place and be happy =)

```
.img_h img{
    display: block;
}
```

Here an example : http://goo.gl/PqYIkN

I have helped

Answer (score 0):

Make the image `display: block` or add `vertical-align: bottom` to it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is possible. And it has been done on this page [Make responsive image fit parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779305/make-responsive-image-fit-parent-container). Hope this helps. please comment back if you do need help or tell me this is useful or not. thanks